# `istream` to array of floats (4-bytes each item)

Tags: c++

I have the following function (so far):

```
void read_binary_file(std::istream is,
                      ByteArray arr)
{
    int length = is.tellg();
    char *buffer = new char[length];
    is.read(buffer, length);
    
    // What to do next? 
    // The goal is to place istream buffer in my `ByteArray` class `values`class,
    // ByteArray - an array of `float`, each item should be 4 bytes from the buffer
}
```

My goal is to place each 4 bytes from the buffer inside my `ByteArray`->values class. Each item should contain 4 bytes from the buffer.

`ByteArray` definition:

```
class ByteArray
{
    ....
    float *values;
}
```

Limitations: I don't want to use `stl`/ `vector` classes.
I couldn't find an example with my current limitations.

Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: Concerning your parameter `std::istream is`, that doesn't work, you can't pass these by value and you would get slicing/truncation if it did work. That said, why do you not want to use containers from the standard library? Would it make any difference to your question (I can't see any)?

Comment: I must have the `istream` parameter, I can't change it. It's a limitation

Comment: Bad luck, because it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt what doesn't work? the buffer is filled, I just want to understand how to add the bytes to my float array

Comment: Use referencje to istream: `istream&`

Comment: @chucha Your use of `istream` makes no sense. Aside from the issue of passing it by value vs reference, another issue I see is that `tellg()` returns the current read position of the stream, so you are setting `length` to the number of bytes that have *already been read* (or skipped) from the stream, and then you are `read()`'ing that many bytes from the current position onward. Why? What is the actual format of the stream data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a ByteArray object and copy bytes from `buffer` to ByteArray::values[] as floats. Assuming that the file is opened in binary mode & contain floats dumped in correct format+endianness, and total data in file is multiple of `sizeof(float)`:

```
class ByteArray
{
    private:
        float* values;
    public:
        void set(char* buffer, int len)
        {
            values = new float[len/4]; 
            for(int itr =0; itr < len/4; itr++)
            {
                values[itr] = *(float*)(buffer+itr*4);
            } 
        }
};

...

arr.set(buffer, length);
```

Note that i) smarter codes are possible but I kept it as simple as possible for your understanding. ii) Ulrich is right, you should pass istream by reference (as well as ByteArray for most practical purposes):

```
void read_binary_file(std::istream& is,
                  ByteArray& arr) 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use istream to send bytes byte by byte you can say

```
arr.values=(float*)buffer;
```

or

```
arr.values=new float[length/4];
memcpy(arr.values,buffer,length);
delete[] buffer;
```

It works until you want to send a float which contains a eof byte by accident. 2 is a float like that, so it isn't uncommon. Then you can't do anything as istream stops at that byte. So I recommend not to send floats byte by byte in stringteams. Send them an other way eg in hexa. (hat way you don't loose precision).

What generated the file you want to read?

Comment: While this may work, recommending C-style casts or `new[]` is almost always a bad idea. Just don't!

Comment: If you can solve it better go for it. Otherwise don't criticize a working solution please. `new[]` was already in use. I know `reinterpret_cast` could be used but in this case they are the same.

Comment: Just replace the `new[]`with a `std::vector`, for example.

Comment: 1.:Read the question please "Limitations: I don't want to use `stl`/ `vector` classes."
 
2.:arr.values was a float* already. (I like `std::vector` too but that isn't the only way)